# delete duplicates values and keep order of elements

Tags: python, sorting, duplicates

How we can remove duplicated values between `list1` and `list2` from `list1` while saving its order?

Example of my code:

```
list1=[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(5,4),(4,7)]
list2=[(1,1),(1,2)]

list1 = list(set(list1) - set(list2))
print (list1)
```

output

> [(5, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7)]

**expected output**

> [(1,3),(3,4),(5,4),(4,7)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005367/retaining-order-while-using-pythons-set-difference

Comment: list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]   No need for any of this set stuff... It doesn't help in a situation like this where you want to maintain the order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a set hashes the elements internally, and so will never be able to maintain the order. If your elements within list are guaranteed to be unique, i.e., they appear only once, you can use the set to filter the elements required:

```
In [26]: list1 = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(5,4),(4,7)]
    ...: list2 = [(1,1),(1,2)]
    ...: unique = set(list1) - set(list2)
    ...: list1 = [x for x in list1 if x in unique]
    ...: print (list1)
    ...: 
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4), (4, 7)]
```

---

In case the same element can be present multiple times within the lists, and you need to keep track of unique number of distinct elements, you will need to maintain a count as well now. Due to which, the logic would look something like:

```
In [29]: list1=[(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(5,4),(4,7)]
    ...: list2=[(1,1),(1,2)]
    ...: 
    ...: from collections import Counter
    ...: 
    ...: count = Counter(list1)
    ...: for element in list2:
    ...:     if element in count:
    ...:         count[element] -= 1
    ...: 
    ...: result = []
    ...: for element in list1:
    ...:     if count.get(element, 0) > 0:
    ...:         count[element] -= 1
    ...:         result.append(element)
    ...: 
    ...: print (result)
    ...: 
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4), (4, 7)]
```

Comment: It seems really overcomplicated to use a `Counter` for this.

Comment: I think since (1,1) is duplicated so it should not be a part of output.

Comment: @kindall Well a dict would be better suited, agreed; Counter just made the creation of the dict easier. Its possible that list1 has the same element `n` times, while list2 has it only `k` times, so it would be needed to check that exactly `n-k` elements are outputted in result.

Comment: @Manjunath There are 2 outputs, look carefully :) . If the intention is to remove all occurences, then the first solution obviously works. If the intention is to subtract the number of times the element occurs in second list, you would need to maintain a count. Any other solution would be suboptimal for time complexity, and since OP is already using a set, I can't give him a solution which performs worse off than his.

Comment: @mu無 Cool, that makes sense, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
```

If `list2` could be larger than a few items, then convert it to a `set` to make checking it faster:

```
set2 = set(list2)
list1 = [item for item in list1 if item not in set2]
```

Note that either of the above snippets will keep any duplicate items in `list1` (i.e., if two items in `list1` are the same, but are not in `list2`). If you want to eliminate internal duplicates in `list1`, which is a behavior of your original solution, this will retain only the first occurrence of each:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
list1 = [set1.remove(item) or item for item in list1
         if item in set1 and item not in set2]
```