# Finding different values in dictionary with the same key in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary lists which has the same key, but different values.

```
Dict_one = {"A": ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]}

Dict_two = {"A": ["a1"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c5"]}
```

I want to get 2 dictionary lists;

One is the dictionary list of values in Dict_one but not in Dict_two.

The other is the dictionary list of values in Dict_two but not in Dict_one.

Result example:

```
Result_one_two = {"A": ["a2", "a3"], "B": [], "C": ["c4"]}
Result_two_one = {"A": [], "B": [], "C": ["c5"]}
```

What is the most pythonic way to get the output?

Edit: They always have the same keys.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the keys are always the same?

Comment: What do you mean by *"best"*? Edit the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: Meanwhile, there's already an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about posting a poor question. It's the first time to use Stack Overflow and I started to learn Python 6 weeks ago. I looked up the way to solve this problem for a lot of hours but I couldn't find an answer. I would try hard and create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the order of the values important? I.e. is `['a2', 'a3']` equivalent to `['a3', 'a2']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.difference` within a dict comprehension:

```
In [29]: Result_one_two = {k: set(Dict_one[k]).difference(Dict_two[k]) for k in Dict_one}

In [30]: Result_one_two
Out[30]: {'A': {'a2', 'a3'}, 'B': set(), 'C': {'c4'}}

In [31]: Result_two_one = {k: set(Dict_two[k]).difference(Dict_one[k]) for k in Dict_one}

In [32]: Result_two_one
Out[32]: {'A': set(), 'B': set(), 'C': {'c5'}}
```

It's better to preserve the values as `set` at the first place tho. In that case you won't need to call the set for each value. Also note that if you're using Python-3.6+ since dictionaries in these versions are insertion ordered the output will be as expected, otherwise you should use an `OrderedDict` to keep track of orders. But if the performance is not an issue here and/or you're dealing with a short data set you can just use a list comprehension as is explained in other answers.

Also, as mentioned in comments, if the order of values is important for you in order to take advantage of set operations and yet keep the order you can use a custom ordered set like what's proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10006674/2867928 by Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: Is order important? Probably best to clarify the poor question before leaping in with a wrong answer.

Comment: @PeterWood I didn't find anything regard the importance of order in question, however I updated the answer with some extra info regard that matter. Besides, if you think this answer is wrong please explain the reasons in details and downvote my answer.

Comment: I'm not talking about dictionary key order. The question has lists as values, the sets could change the order.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: @Kasramvd my time is not free `#happytohelp`

Comment: @PeterWood Well in that case you're better to not let your words be for free too because words by themselves are obscure and their meanings are more often subjective. Now imagine what happens when you echo that effect by not using them in an elaborated manner.

Comment: @Kasramvd I've obviously touched a nerve, apologies.

Comment: @PeterWood Not at all. Discussion! That's what separates us from the rest of the world (at least this is what we think proudly ;)) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
Result_one_two = {
    k: [v for v in vals if v not in Dict_two.get(k, [])]
    for k, vals in Dict_one.items()
}
```

Output:

```
Result_one_two = {'A': ['a2', 'a3'], 'C': ['c4'], 'B': []}
```

And second one:

```
Result_two_one = {
    k: [v for v in vals if v not in Dict_one.get(k, [])]
    for k, vals in Dict_two.items()
}
```

Output:

```
Result_two_one = {'A': [], 'C': ['c5'], 'B': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will help you

```
#first one:
dict_one = {"a":["a1","a2","a3"], "b": ["b1","b2"], "c":["c1","c2","c3","c4"]}
dict_two = {"a": ["a1"], "b":["b1","b2"], "c": ["c1","c2","c3","c5"]}
dict_end = {}
dict_end2 = {}
for i in dict_one:
  for j in (dict_one[i]):
    if j not in dict_two[i]:
      dict_end[i] = j

print (dict_end)
#second one goes below : 
for i in dict_two:
  for j in (dict_two[i]):
    if j not in dict_one[i]:
      dict_end2[i] = j

print (dict_end2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dict_one = {"A": ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]}
Dict_two = {"A": ["a1"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c5"]}

dict(map(lambda k: (k, list(set(Dict_one[k]) - set(Dict_two.get(k, [])))), Dict_one))
# {'A': ['a2', 'a3'], 'B': [], 'C': ['c4']}

dict(map(lambda k: (k, list(set(Dict_two.get(k, [])) - set(Dict_one[k]))), Dict_one))
# {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': ['c5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @kasramvd

```
Dict_one = {"A": ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]}
Dict_two = {"A": ["a1"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c5"]}

Result_one_two = {key:list(set(Dict_one[key])-set(Dict_two[key])) for key in Dict_one.keys()}
Result_two_one = {key:list(set(Dict_two[key])-set(Dict_one[key])) for key in Dict_two.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of dict comprehensions:

```
Dict_one = {"A": ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]}

Dict_two = {"A": ["a1"], "B": ["b1", "b2"], "C":["c1", "c2", "c3", "c5"]}

# Remove this line and just loop over DictOne if using Python 3.6+
sort_keys = sorted(Dict_one)

Result_one_two = {k: [x for x in Dict_one[k] if x not in Dict_two[k]] for k in sort_keys}
Result_two_one = {k: [x for x in Dict_two[k] if x not in Dict_one[k]] for k in sort_keys}

print(Result_one_two)
print(Result_two_one)
```

Which Outputs:

```
{'A': ['a2', 'a3'], 'B': [], 'C': ['c4']}
{'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': ['c5']}
```

**Note:** If you are not using Python 3.6+, iterating over the keys in sorted order or using a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)is necessary, since order is not guaranteed. Otherwise, you can just loop over the keys normally and order is retained.

This also assumes `Dict_one` and `Dict_two` have the same keys.