# Please explain order of sets

Tags: python, set

I've found some code that uses `set`s in Python. I tried to emulate them with lists, but I get different results when `pop()`ing from them!

I opened up Ipython to test how do these things work, and found something pretty strange:

```
In [16]: x
Out[16]: set([])

In [17]: x.add("a")

In [18]: x.add("b")

In [19]: x.add("c")

In [20]: x
Out[20]: set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Shouldn't `'b'` come *before* c, because it was added before it? I don't understand this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python set changes element order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/python-set-changes-element-order)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

> Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion. Accordingly, sets do not support indexing, slicing, or other sequence-like behavior.

The underlying data structure of a set is a hash map, there is lots of information on those [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: But how do they decide where to put the element? Surely they're implemented like arrays, it would be strange if they chose a random number for the index.

Comment: @Bane Just posted a link to that, they use `hash` maps which calculate a hash for each object. `set`s are similar to dictionaries which you may know about.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [wikipedia's set entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)), they say

> An abstract data structure is a collection, or aggregate, of data. The data may be booleans, numbers, characters, or other data structures. If one considers the structure yielded by packaging[1] or indexing,[2] there are four basic data structures:[3][4]
>
> unpackaged, unindexed: bunch
> **packaged, unindexed: set**
> unpackaged, indexed: string (sequence)
> packaged, indexed: list (array)

So sets are *unindexed*, or not ordered in a specific manner.

The python documentation agrees with this (always check the documentation, Python has some of the best I've seen):

[5.7. Set Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

> A set object is an **unordered collection of distinct hashable objects**. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see the built in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections module.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers [jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776732/289011) and [crashmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776807/289011) gave you, you can see it by yourself with an example.

```
>>> stringA="A"
>>> stringB="B"
>>> hash(stringA)
-269909568
>>> hash(stringB)
-141909181
>>> mySet = set()
>>> mySet.add(stringB)
>>> mySet.add(stringA)
>>> mySet
set(['A', 'B'])
```

So I inserted "B" in the set before than "A". Why does it show "A", "B" (when a list would keep the order?). Well, take a look to the hashes calculated for the strings "A" and "B". Which one is smaller? What would happen if you do the same thing with a dictionary where the keys are those hashes?:

```
>>> myDict = {-141909181: "B", -269909568: "A"}
>>> myDict
{-269909568: 'A', -141909181: 'B'}
```

Maybe this helps a bit understanding the sets.