# numpy.unique with order preserved

Tags: python, numpy

```
['b','b','b','a','a','c','c']
```

numpy.unique gives

```
['a','b','c']
```

How can I get the original order preserved

```
['b','a','c']
```

---

Great answers. Bonus question. Why do none of these methods work with this dataset? http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1364341573 Here's the question [numpy sort wierd behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649097/numpy-sort-wierd-behavior?lq=1)

Comment: See [this numpy bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8621).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`unique()` is slow, O(Nlog(N)), but you can do this by following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['b','a','b','b','d','a','a','c','c'])
_, idx = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
print(a[np.sort(idx)])
```

output:

```
['b' 'a' 'd' 'c']
```

`Pandas.unique()` is much faster for big array O(N):

```
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000)
%timeit np.unique(a)
%timeit pd.unique(a)

1000 loops, best of 3: 644 us per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 144 us per loop
```

Comment: The `O(N)` complexity is not mentioned anywhere and is thus only an implementation detail. The documentation simply states that it is *significantly faster than `numpy.unique`*, but this may simply mean that it has smaller constants or the complexity might be between linear and NlogN.

Comment: It's mentioned here: http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/wesm/a-look-at-pandas-design-and-development/41

Comment: How would you preserve the ordering with `pandas.unique()`? As far as I can tell it does not allow any parameters.

Comment: @F Lekschas, pandas.unique() seems to preserve the ordering as default

Comment: @HYRY - The link is broken, need to remove the "/fullscreen": https://www.slideshare.net/wesm/a-look-at-pandas-design-and-development/41

Answer (score 27):

Use the `return_index` functionality of `np.unique`. That returns the indices at which the elements first occurred in the input. Then `argsort` those indices.

```
>>> u, ind = np.unique(['b','b','b','a','a','c','c'], return_index=True)
>>> u[np.argsort(ind)]
array(['b', 'a', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 9):

```
a = ['b','b','b','a','a','c','c']
[a[i] for i in sorted(np.unique(a, return_index=True)[1])]
```

Comment: This is just a slower version of the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to remove duplication of an already sorted iterable, you can use `itertools.groupby` function:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = ['b','b','b','a','a','c','c']
>>> [x[0] for x in groupby(a)]
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

This works more like unix 'uniq' command, because it assumes the list is already sorted. When you try it on unsorted list you will get something like this:

```
>>> b = ['b','b','b','a','a','c','c','a','a']
>>> [x[0] for x in groupby(b)]
['b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: Almost all of the time `numpy` problems get solved way faster using `numpy`, pure python solutions will be slow since `numpy` is specialised.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> #List we need to remove duplicates from while preserving order
>
> x = ['key1', 'key3', 'key3', 'key2'] 
>
> thisdict = dict.fromkeys(x) #dictionary keys are unique and order is preserved
>
> print(list(thisdict)) #convert back to list
>
> output: ['key1', 'key3', 'key2']
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete repeated entries, like the Unix tool `uniq`, this is a solution:

```
def uniq(seq):
  """
  Like Unix tool uniq. Removes repeated entries.
  :param seq: numpy.array
  :return: seq
  """
  diffs = np.ones_like(seq)
  diffs[1:] = seq[1:] - seq[:-1]
  idx = diffs.nonzero()
  return seq[idx]
```

Comment: This only works for numbers. Use `!=` instead of `-`

Answer (score 2):

Use an OrderedDict (faster than a list comprehension)

```
from collections import OrderedDict  
a = ['b','a','b','a','a','c','c']
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
```