# numpy sort wierd behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm looking at the answers to an earlier question I asked. [numpy.unique with order preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved) They work great, but with one example, I have problems.

```
b
['Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' ..., 'Jan-13' 'Jan-13' 'Jan-13']
b.shape
(83761,)
b.dtype
|S6
bi, idxb = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
months = bi[np.argsort(idxb)]
months
ndarray: ['Feb-10' 'Aug-10' 'Nov-10' 'Oct-12' 'Oct-11' 'Jul-10' 'Feb-12' 'Sep-11'\n  'Jan-10' 'Apr-10' 'May-10' 'Sep-09' 'Mar-11' 'Jun-12' 'Jul-12' 'Dec-09'\n 'Aug-09' 'Nov-12' 'Dec-12' 'Apr-12' 'Jun-11' 'Jan-11' 'Jul-11' 'Sep-10'\n 'Jan-12' 'Dec-10' 'Oct-09' 'Nov-11' 'Oct-10' 'Mar-12' 'Jan-13' 'Nov-09'\n 'May-11' 'Mar-10' 'Jun-10' 'Dec-11' 'May-12' 'Feb-11' 'Aug-11' 'Sep-12'\n 'Apr-11' 'Aug-12']
```

Why does months start with Feb-10 instead of Aug-09? With smaller datasets I get the expected behavior, i.e. months starts with Aug-09. I get Feb-10 with all answers to the previous question.

---

This works

```
months = []
for bi in b:
    if bi not in months:
        months.append(bi)
```

---

http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1364341573
Here is my dataset. Try it yourself.

```
import numpy as np
f=open('test.txt','r')
res = []
for line in f.readlines():
   res.append(line.strip())

a = np.array(res)
_, idx = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
print a[np.sort(idx)]
```

Comment: Maybe it's sorting by the string hashes?

Comment: This is a Numpy bug that was fixed in version 1.6.2, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

I believe the problem is actually this.  What version of Numpy are you running?

http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2063

I reproduced your problem because the Ubuntu installation of Numpy I tested on was 1.6.1, and the bug was fixed at 1.6.2 and above.

Upgrade Numpy, and try again, it worked for me on my Ubuntu machine.

---

In these lines:

```
bi, idxb = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
months = bi[np.argsort(idxb)]
```

There are two mistakes:

1. You want to actually use the sorted indices on the original array, `b[...]`
2. You want the sorted indices, not the indices that sort the indices, so use `sort` not `argsort`.

This should work:

```
bi, idxb = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
months = b[np.sort(idxb)]
```

---

Yes, it does, using your data set and running python 2.7, numpy 1.7 on Mac OS 10.6, 64 bit

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 23 2012, 13:06:50) 

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.7.0'

In [3]: from platform import architecture

In [4]: architecture()
Out[4]: ('64bit', '')

In [5]: f = open('test.txt','r')

In [6]: lines = np.array([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])

In [7]: _, ilines = np.unique(lines, return_index = True)

In [8]: months = lines[np.sort(ilines)]

In [9]: months
Out[9]: 
array(['Aug-09', 'Sep-09', 'Oct-09', 'Nov-09', 'Dec-09', 'Jan-10',
       'Feb-10', 'Mar-10', 'Apr-10', 'May-10', 'Jun-10', 'Jul-10',
       'Aug-10', 'Sep-10', 'Oct-10', 'Nov-10', 'Dec-10', 'Jan-11',
       'Feb-11', 'Mar-11', 'Apr-11', 'May-11', 'Jun-11', 'Jul-11',
       'Aug-11', 'Sep-11', 'Oct-11', 'Nov-11', 'Dec-11', 'Jan-12',
       'Feb-12', 'Mar-12', 'Apr-12', 'May-12', 'Jun-12', 'Jul-12',
       'Aug-12', 'Sep-12', 'Oct-12', 'Nov-12', 'Dec-12', 'Jan-13'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

---

OK, I can finally reproduce your problem on Ubuntu 64 bit too:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.6.1'

In [3]: from platform import architecture

In [4]: architecture()
Out[4]: ('64bit', 'ELF')

In [5]: f = open('test.txt','r')

In [6]: lines = np.array([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])

In [7]: _, ilines = np.unique(lines, return_index=True)

In [8]: months = lines[np.sort(ilines)]

In [9]: months
Out[9]: 
array(['Feb-10', 'Aug-10', 'Nov-10', 'Oct-12', 'Oct-11', 'Jul-10',
       'Feb-12', 'Sep-11', 'Jan-10', 'Apr-10', 'May-10', 'Sep-09',
       'Mar-11', 'Jun-12', 'Jul-12', 'Dec-09', 'Aug-09', 'Nov-12',
       'Dec-12', 'Apr-12', 'Jun-11', 'Jan-11', 'Jul-11', 'Sep-10',
       'Jan-12', 'Dec-10', 'Oct-09', 'Nov-11', 'Oct-10', 'Mar-12',
       'Jan-13', 'Nov-09', 'May-11', 'Mar-10', 'Jun-10', 'Dec-11',
       'May-12', 'Feb-11', 'Aug-11', 'Sep-12', 'Apr-11', 'Aug-12'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

---

Works on Ubuntu after Numpy upgrade:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.7.0'

In [3]: f = open('test.txt','r')

In [4]: lines = np.array([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])

In [5]: _, ilines = np.unique(lines, return_index=True)

In [6]: months = lines[np.sort(ilines)]

In [7]: months
Out[7]: 
array(['Aug-09', 'Sep-09', 'Oct-09', 'Nov-09', 'Dec-09', 'Jan-10',
       'Feb-10', 'Mar-10', 'Apr-10', 'May-10', 'Jun-10', 'Jul-10',
       'Aug-10', 'Sep-10', 'Oct-10', 'Nov-10', 'Dec-10', 'Jan-11',
       'Feb-11', 'Mar-11', 'Apr-11', 'May-11', 'Jun-11', 'Jul-11',
       'Aug-11', 'Sep-11', 'Oct-11', 'Nov-11', 'Dec-11', 'Jan-12',
       'Feb-12', 'Mar-12', 'Apr-12', 'May-12', 'Jun-12', 'Jul-12',
       'Aug-12', 'Sep-12', 'Oct-12', 'Nov-12', 'Dec-12', 'Jan-13'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

Comment: no, I need to sort them in their original order. In the example, the first item is Aug-09, so that should come first in the unique list with order preserved

Comment: that gives ['Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Oct-09'
 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09'
 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09'
 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09'
 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Sep-09' 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09' 'Oct-09'
 'Aug-09' 'Aug-09']

Comment: @bizso09 Aha. Use `sort` on the indices, not `argsort`. See edit again, hopefully the last :P

Comment: Yes that is supposed to work. But on my dataset, it doesn't work. I don't know why. You can download it from the link. EDIT. Ok wait, let me try

Comment: Well, I tried your code on 2 computers, and I got both times ['Feb-10' 'Aug-10' 'Nov-10' 'Oct-12' 'Oct-11' 'Jul-10' 'Feb-12' 'Sep-11'
 'Jan-10' 'Apr-10' 'May-10' 'Sep-09' 'Mar-11' 'Jun-12' 'Jul-12' 'Dec-09'
 'Aug-09' 'Nov-12' 'Dec-12' 'Apr-12' 'Jun-11' 'Jan-11' 'Jul-11' 'Sep-10'
 'Jan-12' 'Dec-10' 'Oct-09' 'Nov-11' 'Oct-10' 'Mar-12' 'Jan-13' 'Nov-09'
 'May-11' 'Mar-10' 'Jun-10' 'Dec-11' 'May-12' 'Feb-11' 'Aug-11' 'Sep-12'
 'Apr-11' 'Aug-12']

Comment: I'm running windows 8 64x with Python 32x

Comment: Oh, I use python 2.7... I can't help with python 3 :-/  The problem could also be related to the fact that your original data set has an ambiguous ordering, since it loops through the dates more than once.

Comment: I use python 2.7.3. I mean 32 bit version. It should give the same result everywhere even if it's ambiguous.

Comment: This works without problems ['one','one','two','two','three','three','four','four','one','one','two','three','four'] => ['one' 'two' 'three' 'four']. I think it's to do with the size of the dataset and possibly the architecture of the computer. What OS and python version do you have? I've tried with python 64x and 86x on Win 8 64x