# Pandas drop duplicates on elements made of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say my dataframe is:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[[1,0]],[[0,0]],[[1,0]]])
```

which yields:

```
        0
0  [1, 0]
1  [0, 0]
2  [1, 0]
```

I want to drop duplicates, and only get elements [1,0] and [0,0], if I write:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

I get the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How can I call drop_duplicates()?

More in general:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[[1,0],"a"],[[0,0],"b"],[[1,0],"c"]], columns=["list", "letter"])
```

And I want to call df["list"].drop_duplicates(), so drop_duplicates applies to a Series and not a dataframe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `numpy.unique()` function:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([[[1,0]],[[0,0]],[[1,0]]])
>>> pandas.DataFrame(np.unique(df), columns=df.columns)
        0
0  [0, 0]
1  [1, 0]
```

If you want to preserve the order checkout: [numpy.unique with order preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved)

Comment: @user And [simple is better than complex](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ;).

Comment: @user and if you think one answer is better than the others, it is better to "accept" it so others can know what solution worked best.

Comment: @Omid All answers were great and all upvoted but this is the one I used for its simplicity

Comment: Seems like this or the tuple answer should be added to the pandas codebase.

Answer (score 9):

I tried the other answers but they didn't solve what I needed (large dataframe with multiple list columns).

I solved it this way:

```
df = df[~df.astype(str).duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 8):

#### `drop_duplicates`

Call `drop_duplicates` on tuplized data:

```
df[0].apply(tuple, 1).drop_duplicates().apply(list).to_frame()

        0
0  [1, 0]
1  [0, 0]
```

---

#### `collections.OrderedDict`

However, I'd much prefer something that doesn't involve `apply`...

```
from collections import OrderedDict
pd.Series(map(
    list, (OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(tuple, df[0].tolist()))))
).to_frame()
```

Or,

```
pd.Series(
    list(k) for k in OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(tuple, df[0].tolist()))
).to_frame()
```

```
        0
0  [1, 0]
1  [0, 0]
```

Comment: Why would you prefer something that doesn't involve apply?  The code looks much more readable with apply.

Comment: @wordsforthewise the answer to that question is long but it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way, by turning your series of lists into separate columns, and only keeping the non-duplicates:

```
df[~df[0].apply(pandas.Series).duplicated()]

        0
0  [1, 0]
1  [0, 0]
```

**Explanation:**

`df[0].apply(pandas.Series)` returns:

```
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  1  0
```

From which you can find duplicates:

```
>>> df[0].apply(pd.Series).duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2     True
```

And finally index using that