# Unique values from Numpy Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How do I extract unique values from an `ndarray`?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]], np.int32)

set(arr)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/example.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(set(arr))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637512/7955271 suggests `pandas.unique()` is faster FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]], np.int32)

print(arr)
print(np.unique(arr))
```

```
[[1 2 2]
 [2 2 3]]

[1 2 3]
```

[Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

Comment: I wrote this post since there was no direct question on this topic. I'll accept the answer in 48hrs.