# Unique rows of numpy array while preserving their order

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get the unique rows of an array while preserving the order (of first appearance) of the rows in the result?

The below code tried with variations resulting in a single array.
`array_equal` compares with element positions.

```
import numpy as np
unique = np.array([])
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8,9],[7,8,9,0,1],[9,0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[-8,-7,-6,-5,-4]])

u = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(arr):
       if np.array_equal(unique, i) == False:
        unique = np.append(unique, i, axis=None)
        u += 1

print (unique)
print(u)

>>> print (unique)
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  7.  8.  9.
  0.  1.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5. -8. -7. -6. -5. -4.]
>>> print(u)
7
>>>
```

For this example, the expected result is an array with 6 unique rows.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8,9],[7,8,9,0,1],[9,0,1,2,3],[-8,-7,-6,-5,-4]]
```

Comment: np.append clearly states that with axis None, it flattens everything!  In general `np.append` in a loop is not a good idea.  Stick with list append if you much iterate.

Comment: @hpaulj Tried axis 1 `numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`

Comment: Well, duh.  The array (both) has to be 2d to use axis=1.  Don't try random fixes!  If you don't understand dimensions, and `np.concatenate`, `np.append` will just get you into trouble.

Comment: `unique` works by sorting, so that duplicates are next to each other. Finding duplicates without that sorting takes a lot more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by simply passing the `axis=0` argument to [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), telling numpy to compare the rows to each other. To preserve the order you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637512/12131013), whereby you get the unique indices and use those (once sorted) to select the unique rows of `arr`.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
                [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
                [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                [ 7,  8,  9,  0,  1],
                [ 9,  0,  1,  2,  3],
                [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
                [-8, -7, -6, -5, -4]])
_, idx = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_index=True)
unique = arr[np.sort(idx)]
print(unique)
```

Output:

```py
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 7  8  9  0  1]
 [ 9  0  1  2  3]
 [-8 -7 -6 -5 -4]]
```

Comment: How to preserve the order they came in?