# Numpy delete repeated rows

Tags: numpy, duplicates, row

I simply need to remove the rows that are repeated in an array but maintain one of them, I can't use unique because I need to maintain the order.
Example

```
1 a234 125
1 a123 265
1 a234 125
1 a145 167
1 a234 125    
2 a189 547
2 a189 547    
3 a678 567
3 a357 569
```

I need this output

```
1 a234 125
1 a123 265
1 a145 167    
2 a189 547
3 a678 567
3 a357 569
```

Comment: Are your rows distinguishable by one, say the first, column entry?

Comment: No they aren't... I made the example clearer

Comment: See question regarding this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926898/numpy-unique-without-sort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want ,and uses `np.unique` with the `return_index` keyword argument:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 'a234', 125],
              [2, 'b189', 547],
              [1, 'a234', 125],
              [3, 'c678', 567],
              [1, 'a234', 125],
              [2, 'b189', 547]])

b = a.ravel().view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[1])))
_, unique_idx = np.unique(b, return_index=True)

new_a = a[np.sort(unique_idx)]

>>> new_a
array([['1', 'a234', '125'],
       ['2', 'b189', '547'],
       ['3', 'c678', '567']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

The hackiest part is the view `b`, that turns each row into a single element of `np.void` `dtype`, so that full rows can be compared for equality by `np.unique`.

Comment: @Ali_Sce You're not supposed to include the `>>>` and everything thereafter in your code.

Comment: I didn't do that... I am a beginner but I try to understand things ;)

Comment: When I run it I need to set `new_a = a[np.sort(unique_idx[1])]` otherwise `unique_idx` would be a tuple of two arrays, for the rest its perfect! Really hacky, at least for me!