# Python sklearn - Determine the encoding order of LabelEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encoder

I wish to determine the labels of sklearn LabelEncoder (namely 0,1,2,3,...) to fit a specific order of the possible values of categorical variable (say ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd' ]). LabelEncoder chooses to fit the labels lexicographically I guess as can be seen in this example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['b', 'a', 'c', 'd' ])
le.classes_
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='<U1')
le.transform(['a', 'b'])
array([0, 1])
```

How can I force the encoder to stick to the order of data as it is first met in the .fit method (namely to encode 'b' to 0, 'a' to 1, 'c' to 2, and 'd' to 3)?

Comment: I think you need `OrdinalEncoder` described https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding and http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do that in original one.

`LabelEncoder.fit()` uses [numpy.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which will always return the data as sorted, as [given in source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L83):

```
def fit(...):
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
    return self
```

So if you want to do that, you need to override the `fit()` function. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import column_or_1d

class MyLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):

    def fit(self, y):
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
        self.classes_ = pd.Series(y).unique()
        return self
```

Then you can do this:

```
le = MyLabelEncoder()
le.fit(['b', 'a', 'c', 'd' ])
le.classes_
#Output:  array(['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
```

Here, I am using [pandas.Series.unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html), to get unique classes. If you cannot use pandas for any reason, refer to this question which does this question using numpy:

- [numpy unique without sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926898/numpy-unique-without-sort)

Comment: If someone sutmbled upon this and is asking why it is not working: I was accidently using `le.fit_transform()` which does not call the custom `fit()` method. So check that if it doesnt work for you

Answer (score 2):

Note, there is potentially a better way to do this now with http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html. In particular, see the `mapping` parameter:

> a mapping of class to label to use for the encoding, optional. the
>   dict contains the keys ‘col’ and ‘mapping’. the value of ‘col’ should
>   be the feature name. the value of ‘mapping’ should be a dictionary of
>   ‘original_label’ to ‘encoded_label’. example mapping: [{‘col’: ‘col1’,
>   ‘mapping’: {None: 0, ‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2}}]

Comment: OLD way, NOT Supported NOW, Link also not working

Answer (score 2):

NOTE :: This is not a standard way but a hacky approach
I used 'classes_' attribute to customize my mapping

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le_temp = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_temp = le_temp.fit(df_1['Temp'])
print(df_1['Temp'])
le_temp.classes_ = np.array(['Cool', 'Mild','Hot'])
print("New classes sequence::",le_temp.classes_)
df_1['Temp'] = le_temp.transform(df_1['Temp'])
print(df_1['Temp'])
```

My output Look like

```
1      Hot
2      Hot
3      Hot
4     Mild
5     Cool
6     Cool

Name: Temp, dtype: object
New classes sequence:: ['Cool' 'Mild' 'Hot']

1     2
2     2
3     2
4     1
5     0
6     0

Name: Temp, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Vivek Kumar solution worked for me, but had to do it this way

```
class LabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):

def fit(self, y):
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    self.classes_ = pd.Series(y).unique().sort()
    return self
```

Comment: The whole idea of question was to not sort the order of classes. That's why I chose not to do that in my answer.