# How can I use [C2, ia, ic] = unique(A, 'stable') from MATLAB in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, unique

I'm trying to transfer MATLAB code to Python, but couldn't find an implementation to replace the function `unique` in MATLAB.

In the original MATLAB code, `unique()` is used as:

```matlab
[c,ia,ic]=unique(a,'stable')
```

`c` is an array with unique elements and has the same sequence as `a`.

I know in numpy there is an implementation

```py
c,ic = np.unique(a,return_reverse=True)
```

This function returns a sorted array `c`, but I prefer `c` to have the original sequence as `a` with unique elements.

And `ic` is what I really want. I'm trying to use `ic` to locate some value in `A`.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), there are two parameters that give you the `ia` and `ic` arrays.

Comment: thanks for the comment,but `ia` and `ic` returned by `np.unique()` is based on a sorted array,which is not what I want.I want the selected unique array to keep its original order and `ic` based on this array.

Comment: `C2, ic = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)` gives me the same behavior in both MATLAB and Python (accounting for 1- vs 0-based indexing). Please post an example if you are seeing something different.

Comment: I guess you set `a` as an ordered array or used `unique(a,'legacy')`instead of `unique(a,'stable')`in MATLAB,it will return different `c`.Please try `a=[2,1,0,4,1]`,when I use `c, ic = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)`,`c=[0,1,2,4]`which is in order,and`ic = [2,1,0,3,1]`which is based on the ordered array `c`;When I use MATLAB,`[c,ia,ic] = unique(a,'stable')`,`c=[2,1,0,4]`,which is the same sequence in `a`,and `ic = [1,2,3,4,2]`,different from the result that np.unique give.

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve? Your original question says that you are trying to get `numpy.unique()` to behave the same way as MATLAB's `unique(...,'legacy')`. In your comment, it seems you've switched to wanting to make MATLAB's `unique(...,'stable')` behave like `numpy.unique()`. Which is it? Please update your question with your code (it's impossible to read in comments) and your desired result.

Comment: Sorry for my vague expression in the question,I've changed the question to make it clear.And `unique(...,'stable')` is what I want.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you told us how you plan to use `ic`. Depending on what you want to do, there may be a different answer.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to tell `np.unique()` to not sort the unique values. You can sort the `return_index` array (`ia`) to create the unsorted list of values as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926898/numpy-unique-without-sort/12926989#12926989). From there you can use `np.searchsorted()` to produce the unsorted `ic` array [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251541/numpy-for-every-element-in-one-array-find-the-index-in-another-array/8251668#8251668). It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your recommandation,I also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8251541/14201358) works.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
_,ia, ic = np.unique(a,return_index=True, return_reverse=True)
c=a[ic[ia]]
```

c is the unique elements of a with stable index.