# Set of dictionary values python

Tags: python, dictionary, set, unique

I have a dictionary like this.

```
d = {'ABCS': ['12', '12', '113', '12']}
```

I want unique values like this

```
{'ABCS': ['12', '113']}
```

I tried set and its giving me something like this

```
{'ABCS': [set(['1', '2']), set(['1', '2']), set(['1', '3']), set(['1', '2'])]}
```

Comment: You used `set` on the individual values *in* the list, not on the whole list. Show us your code and we can help you correct it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get unique values from a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve your desired output.  It uses dictionary comprehensions to convert your list values (i.e.  ['12', '12', '113', '12']) to a set, then converts it back to a list.

In [13]:

```
d = {'ABCS': ['12', '12', '113', '12']}
print {k: list(set(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
{'ABCS': ['12', '113']}
```