# Python: Get unique items and sublists in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find a list of unique items and sublists in a list in python 2.7

```
Input : [['P', 'Q'], [['not', 'P'], 'R'], [['not', 'R'], ['not', 'P']], [['not', 'Q'], 'S', ['not', 'T']], 'T']

Output: ['P','Q',['not','P'],'R',['not','R'],['not','Q'],'S',['not','T'],'T']
```

Can anyone suggest how to do it recursively?

My code :

```
def rem_dup(lis):
    y, s = [], set()
    for t in lis:
       w = tuple(sorted(t)) if isinstance(t, list) else t
       if not w in s:
          y.append(t)
          s.add(w)
    return y

def removeDuplicates(prop):
    if isinstance(prop, str):
        return prop
    else:
        out = [rem_dup(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in rem_dup(prop)]
        return out
```

I call removeDuplicates from main method and pass it input. I get below exception:

```
   if not w in s:
   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get unique values from a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: I tried to use code similar to question metioned, but got error. I edited the question with error

Comment: What should be done to fix the error so my function works? Or anyone can suggest another solution?

Comment: Someone please sugest an answer....It is not duplicate question.

Comment: @ssk369 patience is a virtue? It's a Sunday night or a Monday morning on half the planet... you can't expect an immediate response :)

Comment: Anyway, how deeply nested can this thing go?

Comment: And are `['not', 'P']` and `['P', 'not']` unique or not ?

Comment: It can be only ['not','P']...just length = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive solution:

```
def unique(lst):
    s = set()
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, str):
            s.add(el)
        elif el[0] == 'not'
            s.add(tuple(*el))
        else:
            s.update(unique(el))

    return s
```