# Merging two same values in python

Tags: python

For example I have this lists of numbers / id's:

`[1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004]`

how do I merge or make 1002 only one? So it would like this:

`[1001, 1002,1003, 1004]`

I know this pretty basic and I've been looking for a solution in Google for a while and all I see are how to merge `dicts`, which is not what I need. I just need to merge those same values.

Comment: Do you need to keep the same order?

Comment: Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: First, we need to know: is your input sorted?

Answer (score 5):

You can create set from list and convert it back to list:

```
>>> a = [1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004]
>>> a = list(set(a))
>>> a
[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]
```

In case the order matters and needs to be sorted (even though in this example the output looks ordered, the result is not guaranteed to be sorted when using `set`), use:

```
>>> sorted(set(a))
```

Comment: @dizballance, my previous statement was not about the output being sorted yes or no, it was about maintaining the *same* order as the input. So for example `5 2 9 9 1` would return `5 2 9 1` and not `1 2 5 9`.

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not matter, you can use the set built-in function like so:

```
l = [1002, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]

list(set(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not have duplicate values.  You can take a list of numbers, convert it to a set, and convert it back to a list:

```
a = [1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004]
b = list(set(a))
```

will result in 'b' having the value

```
[1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]
```