# Create unique list (my def)

Tags: python

Im not sure why my code does not do what I want (I want to return a list of unique items)

```
B = ["blue", "blue", "red",   "green", "red",  "blue", "yellow", "green", "blue", "red"]
def makeUnique(list):
    unique = []
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if list[i] not in unique:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique
print makeUnique(B)
```

It returns

```
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
```

Edit: idents might be incorrect, when pasting some was missing, so its not a ident error or sth

Comment: Try: `unique.append(list[i])`

Comment: Omg thank you :) I think Im tired...

Comment: Searching other questions already answered is often the best way to find an effective, tested solution.  One line command:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: Or change your loop to `for item in list:` and use `item` rather that `list[i]`. On a side note, it's bad practice to use builtins as variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Maurice Meyer already found the bug in your code, but in general, this algorithm is not optimal - to find unique values in a list, just do:

```
newlist = list(set(oldlist))
```

Comment: `list(set(...))` loses order

Comment: @inspectorG4dget keeping order wasn't explicitly specified as a requirement, but you're right, it is reasonable to want that.

Comment: Or, `>>> np.unique(x);
array(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'], 
      dtype='|S6')` If you're a badass.

Answer (score 2):

You're appending `item`, which doesn't exist in the context of the function. You have to append the item you're iterating over:

```
B = ["blue", "blue", "red",   "green", "red",  "blue", "yellow", "green", "blue", "red"]

def makeUnique(list):
    unique = []
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if list[i] not in unique:
            unique.append(list[i])
    return unique


print(makeUnique(B))  # ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']
```