# Remove subset of an element from a list if there are more than one

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, set

If I have a list like:

```
[u'test_1', u'test_2', u'test_3', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5', u'bananas_6']
```

What would be the best way to just get the following without knowing anything else in advance?

```
[u'test_1', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5']
```

So how I see it, would be something like loop over the list, store the `test` and `bananas` somehow, and if on another iteration, see another of the same start of the string, remove that from the list.

Does anyone know the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you looking for only the first string in the list with a common substring? Or maybe the ordering them by the number at the end? Are you only looking for the first words startign with 'test_', 'bananas_', or 'cake_'?

Comment: @Ben I'm looking for `[u'test_1', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5']` (although the number doesn't really matter) if that makes sense?

Comment: @Rekovni- you're trying to make a smaller list from your big list by some condition. Your example isn't enough for me to guess the condition you're looking for

Comment: @Ben the condition is everything in front of the underscore, so removing all repeated `test` and `bananas` from the list. Everything after the underscore doesn't matter really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep a set of your prefixes and only add items to your filtered list if they're not in the prefix list:

```
start = [u'test_1', u'test_2', u'test_3', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5', u'bananas_6']

seen = set()
end = []

for item in start:
    prefix = item.partition('_')[0]
    if prefix not in seen:
        end.append(item)
        seen.add(prefix)

print(end)  # ['test_1', 'bananas_4', 'cake_5']
```

Answer (score 2):

My main idea uses the dictionary functionality that items are not overridden by default.

I used [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the order of insertion of items.

```
lst = [u'test_1', u'test_2', u'test_3', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5', u'bananas_6']
d = OrderedDict()
for item in lst:
    key, val = item.split('_')
    d.setdefault(key, val) # will not override if item was there before

new_list = [key + '_' + val for key,val in d.items()]
print new_list
```

Output is

```
[u'test_1', u'bananas_4', u'cake_5']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into two sections. The first is to split the string in the list by "_"  then you would have the raw information [test,test,test,banana,cake,banana] and another with the numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6]

You could then find the uniques of the string list with the following solution:
[Get unique values from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python).  Finally append the numbers back on.