# Python 3 unique entries in a list tried using set on list but object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to get unique elements of a list. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python) that recommended using set:

But when I run this code:

```
lst=['foo','bar','foo']
s=set(lst)
```

returns this error message:

> 'list' object is not callable

Edit: miradulo's comment was spot on.

Comment: You likely have a variable named `set` in your program somewhere that is of type `list`.