# How change a os.popen command to subprocess command in python

Tags: python, command, subprocess, popen, deprecated

I know that os.popen is deprecated now. So which is the easiest way to convert a os.popen command to subprocess.

```
cmd_i = os.popen('''sed -n /%s/,/%s/p %s | grep "Invalid Credentials"''' % (st_time, en_time, fileName))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subprocess` code will be roughly equivalent.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    '''sed -n /%s/,/%s/p %s | grep "Invalid Credentials"''' % (st_time, en_time, fileName),
    shell=True)
```

The output is captured into a variable, rather than spilled out onto standard output outside of Python's control. If all you want is to `print` it, go ahead and do that.

This will throw an exception if `grep` doesn't find anything. You can trap it with `except` if you want to handle this corner case one way or another.

However, you could easily replace all of this with native Python code.

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as input:
    between = False
    output = []
    for line in input:
        if st_time in line:
            between = True
        if between and 'Invalid Credentials' in line:
            output.append(line)
        if en_time in line:
            between = False
```

The `output` in this case is a list. Every captured line still contains its terminating newline. (Easy to fix if that's not what you want, of course.)

As an optimization, you could `break` when you see `en_time` (though then the script won't be exactly equivalent to the `sed` script).

This should also be easy to adapt to a scenario where `st_time` doesn't occur exactly in the log file. You will need to parse the time stamp on each line, and then simply start processing when the parsed date stamp is equal to or bigger than the (parsed) `st_time` value. Similarly, parse `en_time` and exit when you see log entries with time stamps equal to or above this value.

Comment: Okay. Thanks . I used subprocess.getoutput() before seeing this answer. Ya I was planning to use native python code. But it requires more work. The code I gave here is a small of the code below:

`'''sed -n /%s/,/%s/p %s | grep "InvalidCredentials" | cut -d"[" -f 2 | cut -d"," -f1 \
        | cut -d"=" -f2 |sort | uniq''' % (st_time, en_time, fileName)`

Comment: The remainder isn't hard to convert to Python either, but a comment is not where to ask for that. Maybe (accept this answer and) post a new question?

Comment: I actually prepared an answer for your new question, but it was deleted before I could post it. In brief, replace `cut` with `split()` and collect the results in a `dict` or a `set`; then you don't need to separately `sort | uniq` anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using shell commands inside python is getting my work done. So no hurry. I was planning to work on it when I get time.

Comment: For the last part maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858531/874188