# Python: Maintain order of input list

Tags: python

My code can remove duplicate items but destroys the order of the list

```
ls = eval(input("Input a list:"))
lss = list(set(ls))
print(lss)
```

I searched and tried some codes but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Don't use `eval(input(..))`.

Comment: What is this code you've found that hasn't worked? It would be a shame if we gave you that  piece of code only to get a response from you that you've already tried it.

Comment: If remove eval and  input ['b','c','d','c','a','a'], the output becomes worst [',', 'd', '[', 'b', ']', 'a', "'", 'c']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get unique values from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028065/7595401

Comment: @ven, `eval` is dangerous. It should not be used with user inputs. Unknown users can input and harm your system. Your best bet is to form list in your code itself. Also, set is unordered.

Comment: @Austin I'll keep in mind, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order is not preserved because you convert your list to set, which is unordered, unique collection.

Try this one:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
items = eval(input("Input a list:"))
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items)))

# for example:
items = [1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2]
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items)))
# output: [1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: This might be a built-in one, but thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = input("Input List: ")
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    if i not in lst2:
        lst2.append(i)
```

print(lst2)

Apologies for my previous failed attempt. Hopefully this one works

Comment: Ugh my bad, I just realized it did not. I'll try to find a solution

Comment: Input List: 1, 9, 8, 7, 1, 6, 8, 5
['1', ',', ' ', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5']

Removing the extra spaces shouldn't be hard, but my method is messy. You could also fix the code to print it without the space

Comment: It also fails for elements of more than 1 character.

Comment: Doing `lst = list(input("Input List: "))`, fixes the above issues.