# Extract unique string values from a list within a list

Tags: python, list, unique-values

So I have a .csv file with a bunch of movie titles, and one of the columns is the listing on Netflix, and it is a list so it has multiple listings, it looks like the spreadsheet below:

[image]

I have managed to extract the individual columns that I need, and so now my main trouble is how to simplify the list of genres so that repeats aren't added.

I have the following code:

```
enter code ef getUniqueGenres(genrelist):
uniqueGenres = []
for titles in genrelist:
    for listing in titles
        if not listing in uniqueGenres:
            uniqueGenres.append(listing)
return uniqueGenreshere
```

I want the code to be able to go through each listing per title and see if it is a unique genre. If it is, it will store it, otherwise it just ignores it.

CLARIFICATION:
The listed_in data colum is a list where each index is its own list. So the unique values would have to take all that into account. I tried doing something like this:

```
uniqueGenres = []
for titles in netflixgenre:
    for listing in titles:
        if not listing in uniqueGenres:
            uniqueGenres.append(listing)
```

But that also did not give me the desired output

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a duplicate question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-the-lists). Nonetheless, the general consensus is the same as [Shaid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66737793/10123438):

Just casting to a set and back to a list is the easiest way to do it. This works because all items in a set must be unique, else they aren't added.

```py
unique_list = list(set(list)).sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using set. here is a example:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
unique_list = list(set(mylist))
```

for list inside a list.

```
import itertools
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['c','a','d']]
// combine multiple list to single list using itertools
final_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
unique_list = list(set(final_list))
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. It just printed out all the data I had. My listen_in set is a list with each index being its own list, so I want to know how to get the unique values for each list within a list

Comment: can you please show the list example? I mean how it looks like.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8eShIxf.png
This is the output shown on the command prompt when I directly print the column I extracted that has the listings

Comment: I have edited my answer. check.

Comment: when I do that, it breaks up the words into characters now, so each index is now a letter instead of a word