# is it possible to recognize unique values ​within the keys in the dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
df.shape
> (12702, 27)

df['x'][0]
>{'a': '123',
  'b': '214', 
  'c': '654',}
```

I try:

```
df['x'].unique()
>TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

is it possible to recognize unique values ​​within the keys in the dictionaries?

or

should i use dummies?

Comment: The keys of a dictionary are always unique. If what you meant to ask was "how to get a list of unique values in a dictionary", you can get those using `set(my_dict.values())`

Comment: Or the set of unique keys in the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Providing an answer similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897477/15744261)

**Edited:**

Sorry for the multiple edits, I misunderstood your question.

From your snippet it looks like your `df[x]` is returning a list of dictionaries. If what you're asking is to get all unique values across some of the dictionaries, you can add the keys using `list(my_dict)` (which will return a list of the keys). Then use a set on the list to return the unique values. Example:

```
values = set(list(df['x'][0]) + list(df['x'][1]) + ... )
```

If you need unique keys across all of these dictionaries, you could get a little more creative with list comprehension to compile all the keys and then wrap that in a set for the unique values.

**Old answer:**

For a list you can simply convert to a set which will remove the duplicates:

```
values = set(df['x'][0])
```

If you want to use these values as a list you can convert that set into a list as well:

```
list_values = list(values)
```

Or in one line:

```
values = list(set(df['x'][0]))
```

Keep in mind, this is certainly not the most efficient way to do this. I'm sure there are better ways to do it if you're dealing with a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to find the unique keys across all the dictionaries in this column. This can be done easily with `functools.reduce`. I've generated some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

possible_keys = 'abcdefg'

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [{key: 1 for key in random.choices(possible_keys, k=3)} for _ in range(10)]})
```

This dataframe looks like this:

```
                          x
0          {'c': 1, 'a': 1}
1  {'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': 1}
2          {'d': 1, 'b': 1}
3  {'b': 1, 'f': 1, 'e': 1}
4  {'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': 1}
5          {'g': 1, 'b': 1}
6                  {'d': 1}
7                  {'e': 1}
8  {'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1}
9  {'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'f': 1}
```

Now the actual meat of the answer:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(set.union, df['x'], set())
```

Results in:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}
```