# I need to write a function that returns a list of how may times a number occurs in another list

Tags: python

My output is:

```
[(5, 3), (5, 3), (5, 3), (10, 2), (10, 2)]
```

but i need:

```
[(5, 3), (10, 2)]
```

My code:

```
def run_length_encode(nums):
    output_list = []
    for i in nums:
        pair = i,nums.count(i)
        output_list.append(pair)
return output_list

run_length_encode([5, 5, 5, 10, 10])
```

Comment: I think you can try by `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your result by using dictionary too,

```
def run_length_encode(nums):
    a = {}
    for i in nums:
      try:
        a[i]+=1
      except:
        a[i]=1
    c = [(x, y) for x, y in a.items()]
    return c

print(run_length_encode([5, 5, 5, 10, 10]))
```

Comment: The method actually passed the tests that i needed to pass.

Comment: @EliottReed Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve this is as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [5, 5, 5, 10, 10]

>>> Counter(my_list).items()
[(10, 2), (5, 3)]
```

---

To fix the logic in your code, you can iterate over [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) instead of complete `list` as:

```
def run_length_encode(nums):
    output_list = []
    #          v Type-casting list to set while iterating
    for i in set(nums):
        pair = i,nums.count(i)
        output_list.append(pair)
    return output_list
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> run_length_encode([5, 5, 5, 10, 10])
[(10, 2), (5, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets. As discribed here. [Other Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python) this returns unique items from a list.

```
def run_length_encode(nums):
    output_list = []
    for i in nums:
        pair = i,nums.count(i)
        output_list.append(pair)
return list(set(output_list))

run_length_encode([5, 5, 5, 10, 10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return output_list` with `return set(output_list)` and it will work.
because `set` doesn't has duplicate items.