# Unravel list within list

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

I have a jupyter notebook, containing a pandas dataframe, with a column PAR (dtype = obj).

```
+------+------------------+
|      | PAR              |
+------+------------------+
| 0    | [[1.2.3, 2.3.4]] |
+------+------------------+
| 1    | [[3.2, 3.2]]     |
+------+------------------+
```

I do not understand how tyo 'clean' each [[list]] in each row, into something like [list].

I can print row contents:

```
print(df['PAR'][1])
print(', '.join(df['PAR'][1][0]))
```

This outputs:

```
[['3.2', '3.2']] 
3.2, 3.2
```

I can also 'strip' each cell into a string:

```
# df['PAR'] = df['PAR'].astype(str)
df['PAR'].replace(r'\[','', regex=True, inplace=True) 
df['PAR'].replace(r'\]','', regex=True, inplace=True) 
df['PAR'].replace(r'\'','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This gives a clean-ish string, although this is not the format that I need:

```
3.2, 3.2
```

But, what I'm looking for is a 1-level list in each row of my df, something like this:

```
+------+------------------+------------------+
|      | PAR              | PAR list         |
+------+------------------+------------------+
| 0    | [[1.2.3, 2.3.4]] | [1.2.3, 2.3.4]   |
+------+------------------+------------------+
| 1    | [[3.2, 3.2]]     | [3.2, 3.2]       |
+------+------------------+------------------+
```

(the spaces between comma and nth element are just for a better reading of the table above).

What would be a common approach to do this?

My next step is converting each new list into a list with only unique elements, following this thread:
[Get unique values from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python)

```
mylist = ['nowplaying', 'PBS', 'PBS', 'nowplaying', 'job', 'debate', 'thenandnow']
myset = set(mylist)
mynewlist = list(myset)
```

So I'd appreciate some help to 'unlist' the lists in each row. A solution with a lambda-function (.map of .join?) would be easy for me to handle.

Comment: For the "unlisting", why not just do `df["PAR"] = [item[0] for item in df["PAR"]]`

Comment: Using list comprehension to assign to a column have to ensure there is no `NaN` values in the column, or else it won't work.

Comment: @pljvp. I updated my answer for the second part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```py
>>> df
                PAR
0  [[1.2.3, 2.3.4]]
1      [[3.2, 3.2]]
```

Unlist* and remove duplicates in one step:

```py
df["PAR"] = df["PAR"].str[0].apply(np.unique)
```

Output data:

```py
>>> df
              PAR
0  [1.2.3, 2.3.4]
1           [3.2]
```

* *Corrected with help from @SeanBean*

Comment: It is the most informative & complete answer for me to learn. Thank you. And thank you @SeaBean & Corralien for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.str[0]` to access the first and only element of the outer list, effectively removing one level of list, as follows:

```
df['PAR list'] = df['PAR'].str[0]
```

**Test data preparation:**

```
data = {'PAR': [
[['1.2.3', '2.3.4']],
[['3.2', '3.2']]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

                PAR
0  [[1.2.3, 2.3.4]]
1      [[3.2, 3.2]]
```

**Run new code:**

```
 df['PAR list'] = df['PAR'].str[0]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                PAR        PAR list
0  [[1.2.3, 2.3.4]]  [1.2.3, 2.3.4]
1      [[3.2, 3.2]]      [3.2, 3.2]
```

Comment: I think `PAR` is not list but a string.

Comment: @Corralien  I just tested out, if `PAR` were a string, it won't give `3.2, 3.2` by the command `print(', '.join(df['PAR'][1][0]))`    I think why OP can use `.replace()` was because he/she used `.astype(str)` before that.    My first impression seeing the column is of `dtype = obj` was also whether it is of string type.  But list items are also listed as `dtype=obj` in `df.info()`

Comment: You have probably right! I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @Corralien  Glad to have friendly discussion here.  We are just answering for leisure :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. +1

Comment: @Corralien   My pleasure!  :-)