# Python : removing other appearances of an item in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I was triying to make a program that can remove any other appearnces of an item in a list but it seems that there is something that I don't understand about loops

```
list = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2]

list2 = list.copy()
list2.reverse()

l = len(list)
for i in range(l - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, l):
        if list[i] == list[j]:
            h = list[j]
            list2.remove(h)
            



list2.reverse()
print(list2)
```

the output: [3, 1, 4]
expected : [3, 2, 1, 4] (I got it after adding "break" under list2.remove(h))

my question is why is "break" necessary here ? the block under if should have been executed only once even without using "break".
in other way when i =1 and j = 4 the if conditon is met so the block is executed removing "2" once from list2
then when i=1 and j=6 "2" is removed again. so why did another "2" get removed ?

Comment: If you are learning loops, please try until you get it (tip: maybe populate a new empty list...). Otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: @iGian yes much simpler, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence.

to use it on your list you can do:

```py
initial_list = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2]
unique_list = list(set(initial_list))
```

Now, for the reason why your code didn't work is that the first 2 is matched twice in the loop and then second one is matched once so you are deleting 2 3 tims.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your question about break, one of the easier ways to remove duplicates from a list is to use [sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp).

A set is a collection type that doesn't allow duplicate values. Converting your list into a set and back into a list will remove the duplicates:

```
my_list = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2]
my_set = set(my_list) #{1, 2, 3, 4}
my_filtered_list = list(my_set) #[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I haven't learned sets yet, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need to add a break statement after `list2.remove(h)` is because without it, your inner loop will continue to execute even after you've removed an element from `list2`. This means that if there are multiple occurrences of the same item in list, you will end up removing all of them from `list2` even though you only want to remove all but one.

When i = 1 and j = 4, the if condition is met because `list[i]` and `list[j]` both equal 2. This means that h = 2 and `list2.remove(h)` is executed, removing the last occurrence of 2 from `list2`. However, the inner loop continues to execute, and when j = 6, the if condition is met again because `list[i]` and `list[j]` both equal 2. This means that h = 2 again and `list2.remove(h)` is executed, removing the second-to-last occurrence of 2 from `list2`.

By adding a break statement after `list2.remove(h)`, you exit the inner loop as soon as you remove an element from `list2`, which ensures that you only remove one occurrence of each item from `list2`.

Comment: Thanks , I dod not know that the block continues to execute

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new list instead of copying existing one and check if item from list A is in list B. If element a is in list B then just pass it and go on next element

```
lista = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2]
listb = []
for a in lista:
    if a not in listb:
        listb.append(a)
print(listb)

[3, 2, 1, 4]
```