# How is the return value of the set function organized?

Tags: python, set

Here is my code:
i used set() and it return [3, 14, 6]

```
items = [3, 6, 3, 3, 14]
set(items)
>>> set([3,14,6])
```

My question is how is the set function organizes it values output. If we think about this, 3 is the first number and 6 is the second on the list, so should it output [3,6,14] instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python set changes element order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/python-set-changes-element-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are unordered. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion.

Like dictionaries, the ordering is based on the [hashes of the stored keys](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys). You cannot rely on this apparent ordering to remain stable.

If you are interested in the underlying data model, the underlying data structure is called a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but in sets only keys are stored, values are left empty.

Comment: ah I see, but so you have to use other functions like sort to organize the number then? One more question though, when you re-compile a program and print hashes, I can see the values are being shuffled sometimes, is that the same case with the set function?Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, there are other possible implementations of storing a set like, e.g. a balanced tree. This is an implementation issue, and no assumptions should be made on the order of a set, no matter how it is implemented. This is the meaning of unordered, that no assumptions should be made regarding its order.

Comment: @tipsywacky: You cannot sort the contents of the set. When using the contents, you can obtain a sorted sequence of those contents, but then you'll be handling a list instead. That's fine for certain operations of course.

Answer (score 1):

@Martijn has given you the reason why, but just a couple more bits that might be useful:

You can use a `dict` with value as key and the position from your original list as value:

```
d = dict( (val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(items) )
# or {val:idx for idx, val in enumerate(items)} in 2.7+
print d.keys() # unique values: [3, 14, 6]
print sorted(d) # unique values in order [3, 6, 14]
print sorted(d, key=d.get) # unique values in original order (based on last occurence of key [6, 3, 14]
```

And slightly a bit more work to get original order, based on first occurence:

```
d = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(items):
    d.setdefault(val, idx)
```