# Tuple unique elements in set changes order in Python

Tags: python, set

I have a tuple of repeating numbers and would like to keep only the unique items but not change the order.  This works:

`values = (30.0,30.0,30.0,15.0,30.0])
print set(values)`

which returns:

```
set([30.0, 15.0])
```

But when I try:

```
values = (2, 1, 2, 1)
```

It returns:

```
set([1, 2])
```

My question is why is it not keeping the order in the second example.

Comment: Sets don't have order.

Comment: As said @SimeonVisser and don't have repeat elements.

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/python-set-changes-element-order?rq=1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: It is a legitimate criticism to say that the OP should not pose a duplicate question, but attacking him for not reading the docs which he may not know about is not constructive and feels hostile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets have no concept of order, but you could use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to achieve what you want:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> values = (2, 1, 2, 1)
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(values))
[2, 1]
>>>
>>> values = (30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 15.0, 30.0)
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(values))
[30.0, 15.0]
```

Comment: Thanks.  @Simon Visser also.