# how to maintain the order of elements in a list?

Tags: python

I am performing a list operation as below in python ,it works fine but the order of elements get sorted ,ideally I want the elements  order in LISTC to be the same as in LISTA removing the elements from LISTB?how can I do that?

```
LISTC = list(set(LISTA) - set(LISTB))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/set-changes-element-order

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462143)? (see the second answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop removing the order from your types.

```
LISTC = [el for el in LISTA if el not in set(LISTB)]
```

Comment: You should create `set(LISTB)` outside the comprehension. Creating it inside the comprehension recreates it on every iteration, defeating the benefit of using a set in the first place.