# Python - how to output set the way/order I declared it

Tags: python, set

I am new to python and things are little why's and how's. Just got to know "SETS" in python and I seem can't print it out the same order as I declare it.
my code:

```
myPersonels = {"Haime", "Brian", "Ryan", "Jonathan", "Patrick", "Robert", 
               "Renzo", "Rjay", "Daniel", "Angelo"}

print(myPersonels)
```

output:

```
 {'Rjay', 'Daniel', 'Jonathan', 'Robert', 'Ryan', 'Renzo', 'Brian', 'Haime', 
 'Angelo', 'Patrick'}
```

I tried the sorted() method but it gives me the alphabetically order and that's not what I want. I want it to print the same order as I declare it. How can I do that? Any help will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: `set`s are not ordered

Comment: Don't use a set -- use a list or tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set changes element order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/set-changes-element-order)

Comment: So there is really no way I can print it out the way I want?

Comment: No reliable way. They have no defined order.

Comment: @JosephReyes Why did you want a set? Would a list do (i.e. `[]`)? If you really want a `set` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: @JosephReyes:  what do you expect when there are duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) -- use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (or [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) if you will never change the values or length), which retains the ordering.

```
In [2]: myPersons = ["Haime", "Brian", "Ryan", "Jonathan", "Patrick", "Robert", 
   ...:              "Renzo", "Rjay", "Daniel", "Angelo"]  ## this is a list
   ...: print(myPersons)
   ...:                
   ['Haime', 'Brian', 'Ryan', 'Jonathan', 'Patrick', 'Robert', 'Renzo', 'Rjay', 'Daniel', 'Angelo']
```

Comment: Well it depends what they want, if they want to avoid duplicates and do O(n) membership testing then a list or tuple is not suitable

Comment: @Chris_Rands premature optimization &c &c

Comment: It's not just about optimization Andrew, the output will be different if they ever have duplicate names

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, but the easiest way to ensure that the input order is identical to the output order (which I take to mean including duplicates, but perhaps I am wrong!) is to use a list. Unless the OP also wants to de-duplicate, a list does exactly what is requested.