# Why do i get an Attribute Error when trying to assign the file to a Model.form??)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my django project i am trying to generate a new edited file out of existing ones, so when i am editing the file and trying to save it to a new model called FileField it says   **AttributeError at /my_blanks/2/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'** . I need to save or asign my edited document and the name of it to my Model.forms  so i can handle it later (download, delete), Can you Help me please?

To solve my task i use DocEdited model then pass it to forms.py

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from my_pdf.settings import PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT
# Create your models here.
from blanks.validators import validate_file_extension

class DocFile(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', validators=[validate_file_extension])

    # uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.document.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)


class DocFields(models.Model):
    doc_fields = models.CharField( max_length=50)


fs_edited = FileSystemStorage(location=PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT)


class DocEdited(models.Model):
    edited_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    document_edited = models.FileField(upload_to='documents_edited/',  storage=fs_edited)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.edited_description
```

Here i use EditedDocumentForm class to make a ModelForm, and then i pass it to my views.py  edit_files function , last 6 lines.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import DocFile

from django import forms
from .models import DocFile , DocEdited


class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocFile
        fields = ('description', 'document')


class RawProductionForm(forms.Form):
    title_forms = forms.CharField(label='')


class VariablesForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        variables = kwargs.pop('variables')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i, variable in enumerate(variables):
            self.fields['custom_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label=variable)

    def get_input_text(self):
        for name, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if name.startswith('custom_'):
                yield (self.fields[name].label, value)


class EditedDocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocEdited
        fields = ('edited_description','document_edited')
```

look at edit_files function last 6 lines

**views.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.files import File

from .forms import DocumentForm, RawProductionForm, VariablesForm, EditedDocumentForm
from .models import DocFile, DocFields

import os
import re
from docx import Document



class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'




def file_list(request):
    documents = DocFile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'file_list.html',{
        'documents': documents
    })


def upload_files(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("file_list")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_files.html',{
        'form': form
    })


def docx_words_replace(doc_obj, regex, replace):

    for p in doc_obj.paragraphs:
        if regex.search(p.text):
            inline = p.runs


            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if regex.search(inline[i].text):
                    text = regex.sub(replace, inline[i].text)
                    inline[i].text = text

    for table in doc_obj.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                docx_words_replace(cell, regex, replace)

def edit_files(request, file_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(DocFile, id=file_id)
    exact_file = Document(instance.document)
    variables = []
    for paragraph in exact_file.paragraphs:
        match = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", paragraph.text)
        variables.append(match)
    for table in exact_file.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                match = re.findall(r"\{(.*?)\}", cell.text)
                variables.append(match)
    exact_file.save('green.pdf')
    temporary_list =  []
    for i in variables:
        for j in i :
            if len(j) > 0:
                temporary_list.append(j)
    variables = temporary_list
    #  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/set-changes-element-order
    variables_set = sorted(set(variables), key=variables.index)

    inputs_amount = len(variables)
    print(variables)
    inputs_list = []
    my_form = VariablesForm(request.POST, variables=variables_set)
    # Start changing variables
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(my_form)
        input_texts = my_form.get_input_text()
        for i, input_text in input_texts:
           inputs_list.append(input_text)

    print(inputs_list)
    my_dict = dict(zip(variables_set, inputs_list))
    print(my_dict)
    for word , replacement in my_dict.items():
        word_re = re.compile(word)
        docx_words_replace(exact_file, word_re, replacement)
    regex1 = re.compile(r"{")
    regex2 = re.compile(r"}")
    replace = r""
    docx_words_replace(exact_file, regex1, replace)
    docx_words_replace(exact_file, regex2, replace)

    if len(inputs_list) != 0:
        files_full_name = inputs_list[0] + '.docx'
        nm = EditedDocumentForm(files_full_name, File(exact_file))
        nm.save()
    return render(request, 'edit_files.html', context={'variables': variables, "form": my_form})


def delete_book(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        got_to_delete = DocFile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        got_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('file_list')
```

Here is my Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/blanks/views.py", line 109, in edit_files
    nm.save()
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 449, in save
    if self.errors:
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/home/grigor/pdf_3/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 246, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Do you mean adding urls.py to code and the html file?

Comment: What? Er, no. I didn't say anything about those. If you got an error, you should post the whole thing.

Comment: Oh i am sorry , i did edit now.