# List comprehension and syntax mistakes with 3 arguments

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is the question:

Implement function `processList2(inputList, specialItem, ignoreItems)` that returns a new list that contains all the items of `inputList` (and in the original order) except

1. Remove any that appear in the list `ignoreItems`
2. Occurrences of `specialItem` (if `specialItem` is not in `ignoreItems`) should become the string `"special"` in the new list.

I am trying to create a new list from `inputList` using list comprehension. I can get `items not in ignoreItems`, but can't seem to figure out how to print 'special' if `item == specialItem`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def processList2(inputList, specialItem, ignoreItems):
    return [item for item in inputList if item not in ignoreItems]
```

a sample output is something like:

```
>>> processList2([1,1,2,2], 1, [2])
['special', 'special']
```

or

```
>>> processList2([1,2,3,4,True,'dog'], 4, [3,5,4])
[1, 2, True, 'dog']
```

Comment: Do you want both of them to be printed separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)

Comment: No. The output I'm looking for is a list with the items in inputString not in ignoreItems, and the string 'special' if the item in inputList not in ignoreItems is the item in specialItem

Comment: Does it have to be done with a list comprehension? When you have multiple conditions like this, it's much clearer to use a loop with `if/elif/else`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **ternary operator** in Python.

```
def processList2(inputList, specialItem, ignoreItems):
    return [item if item != specialItem else "special" for item in inputList if item not in ignoreItems]
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/11018406) for more on the subject.

Comment: @Fukiyel Why would `ignoreItems = set(ignoreItems)` change the order?

Comment: @barmar You can see why in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order

Comment: `in` operator in python has typical complexity of `O(n)` while with set it will be constant `O(1)`. You can still have order maintained

Comment: You're talking about `set(inputList)`. We're talking about `set(ignoreItems)`.

Comment: `set(inputList)` is obviously wrong, since it would also remove duplicates from the input.

Comment: @Barmar Oh my bad, well it wouldn't !