# concatenate words separated by a token in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, set, concatenation

I want to concatenate a word separated by an asterisk in a list of words. The code I am trying is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re

words = ['les','engage', '*', 'ment', 'de','la']

with open ('Fr-dictionary.txt') as fr:
    dic = word_tokenize(fr.read().lower())

l=[ ]
errors=[ ]

for n,word in enumerate (words):
    l.append(word)
    if word == "*":
        print(words[n-1], words[n+1])
        exp = words[n-1] + words[n+1]
        if exp in dic:  
            l.append(exp)
            errors.append(words[n-1])
            errors.append("*")
            errors.append(words[n+1])
        else:
            continue

print(l)
print(errors)


l=frozenset(l)
errors=frozenset(errors)

c=l.difference(errors)

print(list(c))
```

My output is:

```
['la', 'les', 'de', 'engagement']
```

But my desired output has to be in the same order of the original list without:

```
['les','engagement', 'de','la']
```

Is there any other way to get the desired output?

Comment: Tried the [join()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) function? It can take delimiters. You can do without all the loops.

Comment: Sets are not ordered, so you can't expect any specific order by using them.

Comment: Convert your sets to collections. That preserves order.

Comment: @IrfanuddinShafi, After appending the concatenated words, I want to remove the first part of the word, the asterisk and the second part of the word: "engage", "*", "ment"

Comment: @IrfanuddinShafi, how to convert sets to collections? Can you show?

Comment: Read the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    while "*" in words:
        index = words.index("*")
        words.pop(index)
        words.insert(index,words.pop(index-1)+words.pop(index-1))
```