# Change list to set without changing order of elements

Tags: python, list

I want to remove those element from list which has repetition more than one it's like set but order should not be change

```
[4,6,2,6,1,2] should become [4,6,2,1]
```

I'am looking for any inbuilt method or list comprehension

Comment: Sets don't have an order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Similar question that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order

Comment: Since Python 3.7 you can do `stableDistinct = dict.fromkeys(data,"").keys()`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: use `lambda` function and remove duplicates using `set`. Tested on Python 2.7

```
mylist = [4,6,2,6,1,2]
reduce(lambda r, v: v in r[1] and r or (r[0].append(v) or r[1].add(v)) or r, mylist, ([], set()))[0]
```

Comment: I think a fair amount of explanation is needed for this code snippet to be genuinely useful, otherwise, it's fairly hard to read. Also, in case OP is using python3, `from functools import reduce` will be needed at the top