# How to get output in set without it being typecased to list?

Tags: python-3.x, set

I am reading input from a text file, and on certain conditions, I have to perform some operations. The first line in the input file takes in the number of test cases. The next line contains the size of the inputs. The next line consists of the elements.

After taking in the inputs and following the proper operations. Since the order is necessary to maintain I am sorting the output generated.

```py
import sys

test_case = int(sys.stdin.readline())

t = 0
while t < test_case:
    len_a, len_b = map(int, input().split())

    A = set()
    B = set()

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        A.add(int(element))

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        B.add(int(element))     

    operation = int(sys.stdin.readline())

    if operation == 1: print(sorted(set(A.intersection(B))))
    elif operation == 2: print(sorted(set(A.union(B))))
    elif operation == 3: print(sorted(set(A.symmetric_difference(B))))
    elif operation == 4: print(sorted(set(A.difference(B))))
    elif operation == 5: print(sorted(set(B.difference(A))))

    t += 1
```

The expected output is like this:

{10000, 20000, 30000}

{10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 80000, 90000}

{40000, 50000, 60000, 80000, 90000}

{40000, 50000, 60000}

{80000, 90000}

{}

but I am getting:

[10000, 20000, 30000]

[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 80000, 90000]

[40000, 50000, 60000, 80000, 90000]

[40000, 50000, 60000]

[80000, 90000]

set()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following might help you.

**Code**

```
import sys

test_case = int(sys.stdin.readline())

t = 0
while t < test_case:
    len_a, len_b = map(int, input().split())

    A = set()
    B = set()

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        A.add(int(element))

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        B.add(int(element))     

    operation = int(sys.stdin.readline())

    if operation == 1: print(set(sorted(A.intersection(B))))
    elif operation == 2: print(set(sorted(A.union(B))))
    elif operation == 3: print(set(sorted(A.symmetric_difference(B))))
    elif operation == 4: print(set(sorted(A.difference(B))))
    elif operation == 5: print(set(sorted(B.difference(A))))

    t += 1
```

**EDIT**
(For your case to print {} for empty set but not advisable I guess)

```
import sys

test_case = int(sys.stdin.readline())

t = 0
while t < test_case:
    len_a, len_b = map(int, input().split())

    A = set()
    B = set()

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        A.add(int(element))

    for element in sys.stdin.readline().split():
        B.add(int(element))     

    operation = int(sys.stdin.readline())

    if operation == 1: 
      if len(A.intersection(B))!=0:
        print(set(sorted(A.intersection(B))))
      else:
        print('{}')
    elif operation == 2: 
      if len(A.union(B))!=0:
        print(set(sorted(A.union(B))))
      else:
        print('{}')
    elif operation == 3: 
      if len(A.symmetric_difference(B))!=0:
        print(set(sorted(A.symmetric_difference(B))))
      else:
        print('{}')
    elif operation == 4: 
      if len(A.difference(B))!=0:
        print(set(sorted(A.difference(B))))
      else:
        print('{}')
    elif operation == 5: 
      if len(B.difference(A))!=0:
        print(set(sorted(B.difference(A))))
      else:
        print('{}')

    t += 1
```

I've tested it, working fine. Hope this solves your problem !

Comment: It works fine for every input. Unfortunately, when the output should be {} it prints out set(). Is there any fix to that?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that `set()` for empty results, I'll check for better handling

Comment: Actually, `{}` denotes an empty **dict** , only because of that Python is printing the empty set as `set()`, this is the solution I got from some sources.

Comment: if you still want {} to display for your case, i can add up an edit code for that case

Comment: I'm glad if it is helpful :)

Comment: I believe I am using a python version less than 3.6 because the set is not preserving order in some cases. For example, set(sorted(A.intersection(B))) is not storing in order. Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: I think you can use **OrderedDict** for that case refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order.
Another package is available you can try that : https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/