# Why converting a set to list in python does not preserve order?

Tags: python-3.x

```
ar=[10,20,20,10,10,30,50,10,20]  
ar.sort()  
nar = list(set(ar))
```

the result gives me

```
nar = [10,20,50,30] instead of [10,20,30,50]
```

could someone explain this

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order/41379007

Comment: Sets are unordered, no gaurantees therefore that the data will come out in order. You will need to run .sort on nar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick Summary

Sets do not preserve order by definition.

## Still want to remove duplicates but also preserve order?

```py
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> items = [10, 4, 10, 2, 2, 2, 7]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items))
[10, 4, 2, 7]
```

I really hope this helps!