# why casting list to set doesn't respect ascending order when list is made up of numbers in which are in form of string

Tags: python, list, set

I've been sorting list's values in ascending order and I found to cast the list into set and thereafter cast it back into list solves the problem for example

```
attempted = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
print(list(set(attempted))) # output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and also is the same when `list` is made up by alphabets but when numbers are in the form of string(`str`) this does nothing, for example

```
lit = ['2','4', '1', '3', '5']
print(list(set(lit))) # output keeps changing by the time
```

but when `sorted` method is applied to the list it respects the ascending order like

```
lit = ['2','4', '1', '3', '5']
res = sorted(list(set(lit)))
print(res) # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

and I don't understand why set can't sort the numbers which are in the form of string(`str`) by default without adding `sorted` method.

waiting for your good answers, suggestion and documentations about it

Comment: a `set` doesn't maintain order so converting it back to `list` will give you a random order.

Comment: @VishalSingh No, it wouldn't give the random order.

Comment: it gives me random order when it is number in form of string only

Comment: a `set` is not sorted as others have mentioned, just because sometimes when you cast `set` on a sequence it maintains the order when printing the `set` does not guarantee that the same will be true over time. it states this fact in the first line of the official documentation --> https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a list to a set changes element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order)

Comment: @VishalSingh I know that it change the order and I found that the order it respect is an ascending order at the most but I didn't understand that why it didn't respect it when is numbers in form of string

Comment: there is no documentation supporting that it maintains any order whether it's ascending for descending.

Answer (score 0):

set only removes the duplicates but doesn't care about the order.So after converting it to set convert it back to list to get the right order.

Comment: I don't think if understood my question well but I was wanted to know why it respects the ascending order but not on the numbers which are in form of string

Comment: Did you add anything compared to the comments that were already posted?

Comment: i got your question and my answer is right. sets only care for numbers not for strings and when numbers are placed in quotes they are strings now. So there order doesn't matter.

Comment: You are wrong about alphabets.I tried that and it gave me random order every time.

Comment: You should checkout the documentation on these things.