# Reverse the elements of a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, set

I was trying to find a way to reverse the elements of a set. In the process of conversion we should not convert set into any other data type like list
and we should not use recursions

Is their any way for it ?

Ex :
S= {1,2,3}

Output:

3,2,1

Comment: `set` objects do not provide any public way to reverse them because *sets are inherently unordered data types*. Any particular order that it iterates in is arbitrary. Barring things like hacking the internals, you'd have to use an auxiliary, ordered data structure like a list (or implicitly the call stack, using recursion), but again, this doesn't really make sense because code you write shouldn't rely on any order about sets.

Comment: If you wanted to iterate over the elements in the reverse order of the order in which you inserted them, you can use a `dict` instead, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792680/5468953), since these preserve insertion order - so if `d` is a `dict`, you can iterate over `reversed(d)`. (Commenting as it's not clear if this is what OP was asking, but I was wondering about this use case and ended up in this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this obeys your rules and prints the set in descending order:

```
s = {1, 2, 3}
for _ in range(len(s)):
    elem = max(s)
    s.remove(elem)
    print(elem, end=',' if s else '')

# 3,2,1
```

Answer (score 4):

Sets are not ordered. So, the sets `{1, 2, 3}` and `{3, 2, 1}` are essentially the same.
You must use lists if you want ordered elements.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[::-1]
print(list2)
```

Output is

```
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

**EDIT:**  If you want to use for loop:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = []
for x in range(len(list1)-1, -1, -1):
    list2.append(list1[x])
    
print(list2)
```

The logic of this code is:
The `range(a, b, c)` function takes 3 arguments : from `a` to `(b-1)` with each step of `c`.
So, we move from the last element ***(len(list1)-1)*** of the `list1` upto the first element ***-1*** with a step of ***-1***, so that it decreases with each step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I understand that
So can't we print their in reverse order

Comment: You could convert it into a list and then reverse that, which would print them in reverse order from how they print normally, although it doesn't really make much sense to use a set for this kind of case.

Comment: I know that but I want know is there any way by using for loop

Comment: ya! But I want to use only set not list . Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @pavankrishna, note that ***SETS ARE NOT ORDERED***. So, you can't guarantee that  after performing any operation on the set, the "order" of the set remains the same. Also, you can't access the elements in a set the "normal" way, like we do in lists: `my_list[index] = allowed`, `my_set[index] = not allowed`

Comment: I am not trying to change the order of Elements in a set. I was trying only to print them in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

Works for small numbers. Might not work for large numbers and not for characters and other items

```
s = set()
s.add(1)
s.add(3)
s.add(2)
#forward list (ascending order)
flist = [i for i in s]
# >>> [1,2,3]
#reverse list (descending order)
rlist = [flist[len(flist)-i-1] for i in range(len(flist))]
# >>> [3,2,1]
```