# Combining Tuples into a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```py
[(1,2), (5,10), (2,5)]
```

And I would like to get a list of unique numbers

```
[1,2,5,10]
```

May I know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Because this is just a simple example I need for the program.

Comment: But it gives the result you want.

Comment: Why not do `list(tuples[0] + tuples[1])`?

Comment: Question: in a comment you said that the order is important, for `[(5,10),(2,5), (1,2)]`  should it be `[5, 10, 2, 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work? I've appended each item to a new list, then use `set()` to get the unique items

```
new_lis = []
lis = [(1,2),(5,10),(2,5)]
for x,y in lis:
    new_lis.append(x)
    new_lis.append(y)
    
result = list(set(new_lis))

[1, 2, 10, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy to do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

x = [(1,2),(5,10),(2,5)]
result = np.array(x).reshape(-1)
```

If you want to get unique values, use `set()` like this:

```
result = set(np.array(x).reshape(-1))
```

Comment: Good idea, but the order is important

Comment: If you mean the order it was in the initial list, instead of `set()` you can do this:
`list(dict.fromkeys( ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"]))`

Answer (score 1):

one-line solution:

```py
tuples_list = [(1,2), (5,10), (2,5)]
res = sorted(list(set(sum(tuples_list, ()))))
```

Comment: `sum( , ())`  is not designed to chain iterables, see doc

Comment: ...and `sorted` is nonsense: with `[(5,10),(2,5), (1,2)]` you get the same result. The order of insertion should be respected

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

L = [(1,2), (5,10), (2,5)]

flat_no_dupes = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(L))
```

Using [itertools chain from iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list, and making [a set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=set#sets) to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use a set comprehension to achieve this result. The set comprehension iterates over the tuples, then over the values in each tuple. We build a set from these values `y`.

```py
a = [(1,2), (5,10), (2,5)]
{y for x in a 
   for y in x}
# {1, 2, 10, 5}
```

Comment: Do you know why the order is constant in this case but if I do, for ex `print(set("aBc"))`, then change?

Comment: In Python, sets do not necessarily preserve order.

Comment: ok, but you used a set-comprehension, right?

Comment: Yes, that is a set comprehension.

Comment: So with a comprehension the order is "fixed"? I run it multiple times and did not notice any changes...

Comment: Possibly useful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order

Answer (score 0):

A version which respects the insertion order:

`[(1,2), (5,10),(2,5)] -> [1, 2, 5, 10]`

`[(5,10), (2,5), (1,2)] -> [5, 10, 2, 1]`

```
l = [(5,10),(2,5), (1,2)]

# flat list
l_flat = [i for pair in l for i in pair]

# dictionary of value-position pairs (1st occurence only)
d = dict.fromkeys(l_flat, None)
for i, v in enumerate(l_flat):
    if d[v] is not None:
        continue
    d[v] = i

# order per position and get values
res = [k for k, _ in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])]

# check result
print(res)
```