# set() in Python

Tags: python, set

I have used the set() function but I am confused.

```
x = set("car")
print(x)
```

Why does this code output: "a", "c", "r" and not "car"?  Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `set` constructor expects iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set()` function converts an iterable into a set. Because a string is an iterable collection of characters (well... of shorter, one-character strings), `set("car")` becomes the set of its characters e.g. `{"c", "r", "a"}`. (The order is random.)

There's three ways you can make a set containing the string "car":

1. Make the set directly using braces:

```py
my_string = "car"
my_set = {my_string}
```

2. Put the string into another iterable and convert that

```py
my_string = "car"
temp_tuple = (my_string,)
my_set = set(temp_tuple)
```

3. Make an empty set and add the string to it

```py
my_string = "car"
my_set = set()
my_set.add(my_string)
```

If you just want a set containing specifically the word "car" you can construct this as a literal:

```py
my_set = {"car"}
```

but I expect the actual problem you're trying to solve is more complex than that!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the main properties of `set` in Python.

- They can't contain duplicates
- They're unordered

So things like this one just happen.

```
>>> set("car")
{'a', 'r', 'c'}
```

---

I suggest you to read this useful documentation about Python's `set`.

- [Python - Set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)
- [Programiz - Python's Set](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)
- [W3Schools - Python's Set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

---

If you really want an ordered set, there's something that can be useful to you.

- [OrderedSet](https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/11/python-ordered-sets-an-overview.html)

I would suggest you to check [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792664/converting-a-list-to-a-set-changes-element-order) too.

Comment: Thank you. And one more question. When do we use set("ford") and when car = {"ford", "honda"}

Comment: Well, if you want a set[str] you use the second one, while the first one will return a set of characters taken from the "ford" str. They will both be a set[str] since Python has no "char" type, but the first one will be like an unordered {"f", "o", "r", "d"}.

If the answer was helpful please accpet it to mark it as a working one.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want one item in the set

do this

```
x = set(["car"])
print(x)

## or create a set directly like this

x=set({"car"})
```

set takes an iterable...a string is an iterable so it gets split
if you pass a list even with one item..it will  remain as such

Comment: yes..that was typo

Comment: `{"car"}` is a set already, you don't need to pass it through `set()`